# Getting started with AI (Artificial Intelligence)

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I recently got interested in Artificial Intelligence. In my daily life I am a software engineer at a company that develops mobile apps. I am wondering what is the best way to read up on AI? What are 'must-read' books for information about AI?

Comment: my CS440 book is really good.. i'm going to dig it out and give you the the info

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Off the top of my head, the very classic, must-read, heavy book that will help you throughout your AI experience : [Artificial Intelligence, A Modern Approach](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0136042597).
Don't be scared by the size, this book is trying to explore multiple kinds of AI, and the authors warn that the reading of the entire book will need nearly a 2-semester period.

If you want to focus on game development and skip the linguistics/robotics/philosophical part of AI, just buy [Artificial Intelligence for Games](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0123747317), this book will give you a fine overview of the basic algorithms and game logic behind different types of games.

I read this one last month and am currently reading the 'Modern Approach' one because, let's be honest, when I read some pages of that big AI Bible I was discouraged so I tried the more game-oriented one and was happy with it.

Comment: I second the recommendation of "A Modern Approach" - it's just a really well written text book for an interested CS student..

Comment: "Artificial Intelligence, A Modern Approach" is definitely THE must read book if you want to get a good broad overview of what AI is about. It doesn't get into much detail though. Other than that: AI is such a vast field that it is difficult to recommend much else. It really depends on what you want to do. If you want to learn about machine learning Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning by Bishop is the go-to book (warning: There be math ;)). Computer vision has it's own books. So does reinforcement learning, data mining and every other aspect of AI. So it really depends.

Answer (score 4):

You could also try BerkeleyX AI course that is available on edX.

More info here: [CS188.1x Artificial Intelligence](https://www.edx.org/course/uc-berkeley/cs188-1x/artificial-intelligence/579)

I haven't taken this particular one, but the quality of presentation is generally very good.

If you go through the [archived course](https://www.edx.org/course/uc-berkeley/cs188-1x/artificial-intelligence/369) that already ended, you can just study at your own pace. However, if you register for the upcoming one you may also get to submit your exercises and take exams, and even receive a certificate at the end. But it will probably start around Fall.

Also their forums are great for asking questions of fellow students and community assistants.